# How to check if a user is authenticated in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I understand that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` must be true to check if a user is authenticated. I am however, unsure of which of these properties can be null. So I currently have this code:

```
if (User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
{
    // ...
}
```

Is that correct? Or can any of the null conditional operators be omitted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using ASP MVC (also aspnet core) the User.Identity is always set. If a user hasn't been authenticated the identity will have no name and IsAuthenticated will be false, so you are safe using

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //..
}
```

If it isn't valid then User.Identity will be null.

Comment: but if User.Identity is null, then the above code would result in a NullReferenceException? :)

Comment: You also can go with **Request.IsAuthenticated**, that will help you with a check for the null user.